# Execute a shell command and get its output inline in cmake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to execute multiple commands as part of a custom target. It looks something like this:

```
add_custom_target(foo ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ...
    # more commands here
)
```

Each command has multiple options (here represented by the ellipsis) so I was looking for a way to do this without intermidiate variables (as they would make the code hard to read and modify).

In bash I would do `$(...)`. Is there some equivalent of this in cmake?

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need `${CMAKE_COMMAND}`, you can just call e.g.

```
add_custom_target(foo ALL
    COMMAND echo "hello" "cruel"
    COMMAND echo "world")
```

Note that this destroys cross-platform compatibility.